# Date not being sent over to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, phpmyadmin, forms

I have looked everywhere, but I can't seem to find the correct code. I have an html form take in a date from the user using the "date" input.

index.html:

```
<form name="myform" action="process.php" method="POST">
     Date: <input type="date" name="date"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Process.php:

```
$link=mysqli_connect("my.sql.server", "username", "psswd", "database_name")
$date = $_POST['date'];
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO visit_exclude_dates (date) VALUES (CAST $date AS DATE)");
```

the value of $date when it comes out of the form is in the yyyy-mm-dd format, and I am able to successfully write to the database. My problem is that when I read the database, the date is being shown as 0000-00-00. So I assume that the problem is with this line:

```
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO visit_exclude_dates (date) VALUES (CAST $date AS DATE)");
```

EDIT:
I would like to note that visit_exclude_dates is the name of my table

Comment: What makes you believe you can "successfully write to the database"?

Comment: I suppose successfully is not a good term, but I know something is being written to the database, because more indexes are being added to the 'date' variable of my table. I am able to see this in phpMyAdmin, and by using 'SELECT date FROM visit_exclude_dates'

Answer (score 2):

Try adding ticks around the date field in your query.  Provided you're SURE the input is Y-m-d format, It'll most likely fix your issue:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));
$result = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO visit_exclude_dates (date) VALUES ('{$date}')");

if(!$result) {
    echo "Error: " . $link->error);
    die();
}

$result->close();
$link->close();
```

Comment: Editing and removing the Cast function.  If you sanitize your input with strtotime, this is much neater.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? also the code above, was not able to write to the database, no values were returned, not even 0000-00-00

Comment: What do you mean no values were returned?  This code will return FALSE if it didn't work, and a result object if it did.  Did you look in your database?  Did it write anything to the db at all?  I am editing my code with something that will show you if there was a mysql error.

Comment: I am using phpMyAdmin, before I updated the code, my table was filled with my attempts at adding dates (and it would show each of them as 0000-00-00, unless I added queries to the table by using the phpMyAdmin interface). Now nothing is being updated.

Comment: Put in that code with the error checking, and let me know if you get a MySQL error.  It'll help us get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Nothing is being echoed out. I went to phpMyAdmin, but my table didn't change

Comment: If it's just dying and not doing anything, you probably have a syntax error somewhere in your code.  Put an echo down at the bottom like echo "made it"; and see if it prints.  If not, your script is dying before it executes fully.  Check your web server logs for PHP Fatal errors and see what you find.

Comment: Wow!, I echoed "made it"; at the bottom and It didn't show up, and I don't have access to those web server logs at the moment (I'm on a very restricted computer).

Comment: Yeah you'll need to go through your code and look for syntax errors.  Missing semicolons, make sure your parenthesis match up, etc.  The code I posted is syntactically correct, I made a test script and it's all good.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**[Use strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**

You will need to force a specific pattern that the user has to input.