# Getting blank date adding date to database (wordpress, php)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date

Basically I'm trying to add a date to my database (just a date, not datetime)

here's what I have so far:

```
$wpdb->insert(
    'my_table',
     array('date-adding'=>date('Y-m-d', '1994-06-14')), 
     array('%F')
);
```

it simply inserts `0000-00-00` so its something simple that's wrong - probly the `%F` but can't figure out what.

Thanks

Comment: A missing inverted comma perhaps? Although quite why that doesn't just error out, I'm not sure.

Comment: is it a typo or are you missing a `'`?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/date   date() does **NOT** use a string for its timestamp input. You're trying to format the number `1994`, which is all that's going to be left of your date string after PHP tries to conver it to an integer, meaning you're going to be dealing with Jan 1st, 1970, approximately 12:33am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [PHP `date()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is wrong, what are you trying to accomplish? The second parameter should be a UNIX timestamp, not a date string. Since you're just feeding it a static time string too, just use '1994-06-14', no reason to try and use the `date()` function.

If you want something dynamic using a string, try this:

`date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dynamic_date_string))`

**EDIT AFTER DISCUSSION:**
The root problem turned out to be the third parameter formatting string formatting the DATE as a float. Since there was no reason to format the date, removing that optional parameter fixed the issue. Also, formatting the input as a string using `%s` would have worked.

Comment: Simply the user has an input - they enter their date of birth and it saves it to the database. So i'm simply trying to add any date I have as a string to my database but everything keeps coming out blank :S

Comment: @JamesB123 You could show us your input form then, to make it clearer as to "how" to answer.

Comment: Sorry I shortened everything for the question - right now my code is literally the above - i'm just passing a static string in ('1994-06-14') into my database table, all that's missing above is the php tags and global $wpdb;

Comment: @JamesB123 If you're trying to pass data as a "string", then use double-quotes instead. I.e.: `$string="1994-06-14";` as compared to `$string='1994-06-14';` is not treated the same.

Comment: Tried that, still blank - coming up in database as 0000-00-00

Comment: @JamesB123 Try using the following as an example: `<input type="text" name="date_input" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date); ?>" />`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Single vs. Double quotes has no effect here, in fact he should use single quotes since there's no special characters to parse.

Comment: @GeorgeYates Ah ok thanks George. Trying to find a solution for the OP, seems like it's the `%F` that is giving problems

Comment: @JamesB123 Use the `$wpdb->insert` method without the third parameter, since you're formatting with `date()`, you don't need WordPress to format the data. Also, verify that the column name is `date-adding`

Comment: @JamesB123 Also, in your script, play around with showing what `$wpdb` actually did. I would, after my `$wpdb->insert` run `var_dump($wpdb->last_query); exit();` to verify that the query executed was what I wanted.

Comment: Aha! Thank you George, changed it back to %s and it worked, ofc cause the php converts it to the correct date format, ah thankyou!

Comment: That var_dump line is really useful! Could you add the change to %f->%s in the answer (possibly include the var-dump as well - your choice) so I can accept it

Comment: Ya, the third parameter is optional and is really only needed if you're sanitizing data, since you're forcing a format on your input, you don't need it. Also, look at [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Class_Variables), as those variables will help you get out of a lot of sticky situations.

Comment: @GeorgeYates Right on George, glad to see a solution has been found, cheers :)

Comment: @GeorgeYates Definitely a +1 on my part.

Answer (score 1):

### Possible solutions:

Use `strtotime()` and `date()`:

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

**Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2487938/1415724**

---

### EDIT #2

Have a look at this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>..</title>
<body>
<form action="work1.php" method="post">
Value1: <input type="text" name="date"><br>
<input type="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</head>
</html>

<?php
$username="root";
$password="abcdef";
$database="test_date";
$date=$_POST["date"];  // Your First Problem Post value
echo $date;
echo "i m here";
$date = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($date));   // 2nd Problem Date Format
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$query = "INSERT INTO date VALUES('','$date')";

mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();
?>
```

**Source: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/300356/date-stored-in-mysql-as-0000-00-00**

### or:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));
$result = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO visit_exclude_dates (date) VALUES ('{$date}')");

if(!$result) {
    echo "Error: " . $link->error);
    die();
}

$result->close();
$link->close();
```

**Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16991316/1415724**

---

### "EDIT"

Given that the data is coming from an input form field, here is an updated answer.

If you're trying to pass your data as a "string", then use double-quotes instead.

I.e.: `$string="1994-06-14";` as compared to `$string='1994-06-14';`

are not treated the same in PHP.

Try using the following as an example:

```
<input type="text" name="date_input" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date); ?>" />
```

Comment: Still coming out blank :S

Comment: @JamesB123 It's harder for me than others to work without seeing full source code, sorry.

Comment: @JamesB123 Check what your DB table/values is set to.

Comment: @JamesB123 Have a look at this answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/12120457/1415724

Comment: thanks was having a look at that but still nothing, the only thing I can think is that the %F should be something else - in phpMyAdmin the format is literally set to date and comes out as 0000-00-00 if I enter an sql query into myAdmin everything works fine

Comment: I can add other fields fine, if I have a VARCHAR column (say name) doing this:
$wpdb->insert(
    'my_table',
     array('forename'=>"james"), 
     array('%s')
);
works perfectly

Comment: @JamesB123 What happens of you remove `array('%F')` ?

Comment: @JamesB123 Or try using double quotes `array("%F")` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));` That's wrong, the MySQL DATE datatype requires 'Y-m-d' formatting.

Comment: @GeorgeYates Thanks for that George, yet I included the source of the document underneath that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2487938/1415724 --- was only quoting that from an SO accepted answer.